# (HTML) Позиционирование блочного элемента относительно разрешения

Tags: html, css

При изменении разрешения экрана блочный элемент backline изменяет положение. Как сделать что бы он зафиксировался позиции несмотря на изменения в разрешении.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="disctiption" content="some text here"/>
        <title> Титульник </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Final-css.css" type="text/css" href="">
    <body>
                <div class="insta">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
                        <img src="img/121.jpg" alt="instagram">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="WK">
                    <a href="https://vk.com/">
                        <img src="img/122.jpg" alt="WK">
                    </a>
                </div>
        <h1 class="logo">
            GOOD LoGo
        </h1>
        <div class="heat"></div>
        <img class="center-pictures" src="img/222.jpg" alt="1">
    <div class="backline"></div>
    </body>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.heat {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 0.3%;
    opacity: .3;
    top: 130px;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
}
.insta {
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    margin-left: 80%;
    top: 40px;
}
.WK {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 70%;
    top: 40px;
}
.center-pictures   {
 position: absolute;
top: 135px;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100%;
left: 0%;
}
.backline {
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: .5;
    display: block; 
}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно явно прописывать высоту для картинки и использовать `object-fit` для обработки поведения заполнения. Иначе картинка через тег `<img />` будет подстраиваться по ширине, а высота будет какая попало.

Обратите внимание, что свойства `background-*` для тега `<img />` не работают, они предназначены только для заданного изображения через `background-image`.

```css
.heat {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 0.3%;
  opacity: .3;
  top: 130px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}

.insta {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 80%;
  top: 40px;
}

.WK {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 70%;
  top: 40px;
}

.center-pictures {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0%;
}

.backline {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: .5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="disctiption" content="some text here" />
  <title> Титульник </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Final-css.css" type="text/css" href="">

  <body>
    <div class="insta">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
        <img src="img/121.jpg" alt="instagram">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="WK">
      <a href="https://vk.com/">
        <img src="img/122.jpg" alt="WK">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="logo">
      GOOD LoGo
    </h1>
    <div class="heat"></div>
    <img class="center-pictures" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/604/800/600.jpg?hmac=2HXoQyJFIv12wDtXpQtgfuj-dehb1MXwiplk39VHs9k" alt="1">
    <div class="backline"></div>
  </body>
  </header>
  </body>

</html>
```